# Is it idiomatic to say "truth hinges"?

Tags: meaning

Is it idiomatic to say "truth hinges"? I am wondering if we need to say "truth hinges upon" or "truth hinges on something" instead of just "truth hinges". Because the definition being "To be contingent on a single factor", you would think "truth hinges" which means "truth is contingent on a single factor", you don't need to add "on something".

For example:

> I always believed that truth hinges.
>
> I always believed that truth hinges upon a single factor.

Should mean the same thing? No? Could you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things that "hinge" are things with a variable outcome. When A "hinges" on B, that means A "depends" on B. Even though the definition says to hinge is "to be contingent on a single factor" (requiring that there must be a single factor), you still have to state the single factor.

Examples:

> "His future will hinge upon what the police bodycam shows."
>
> "The championship hinges on whether those two players remain on the
>   team."
>
> "What college I go to hinges upon my SAT score."

or maybe even,

> "What college I go to hinges on a single factor."

but not,

> "What college I go to hinges."

Even though "to depend" can be used by itself:

> "Will they get back together? That depends."
>
> "I don't know; it all depends."

I don't think you can say "hinge" without telling what it hinges "**on**".

"The truth hinges." doesn't sound right.